# Finding the most balanced combination to obtain a result

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I'm working on a bash script and I've come across a problem that I can't solve.

*EDIT: Thanks to @markp-fuso and @pjh for their help !*

I have 2 arrays of integers, `dividers_1` and `dividers_2` and a third variable `product` containing an integer.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
dividers_1=("1" "2" "4" "6" "8" "9" "12" "16" "18" "24" "32" "36" "48" "64")
dividers_2=("1" "2" "3" "4" "7" "9" "12" "16" "18" "24" "27" "32" "36" "48" "54")
product=16
```

The aim is to find the most balanced combination of two numbers, one from the first array, the other from the second array (in any order), whose multiplication equals the variable `product`.

By the most balanced combination I mean that the 2 terms of the multiplication are distributed as evenly as possible.
For example, if `product=16`, the most balanced combination would be `4x4`, compared with `1x16` which is not distributed equally.

Obviously, a perfectly balanced combination is not necessarily possible, so if it is not possible because of the values available in the two tables, then we would look for a less evenly distributed combination.
For example, if we consider the previous tables, and `product=64`, although the `8x8` combination is the most balanced, it is not possible because 8 is not present among the values in one of the tables.
So the most balanced combination becomes `4x16` (or `16x4`).

Finally, if no combination is possible, an error message is returned.

I have the feeling that the solution lies in a recursive function, but I'm not very good with that.
I'm open to suggestions. The ideal is to have as few dependencies as possible because of the medium in which the script will eventually be run.
I'm currently using bash 5.2

EDIT1:
As @markp-fuso asked :
This is what I mean by *evenly distributed*. In a multiplication where the two terms are evenly distributed, the terms are ideally identical, or at best the difference should be the smallest. For example, if the product you are looking for is 900, the ideal distribution is 30x30 (a difference of 0) . The next most balanced distribution would be 25x36 or 36x25 (difference of 11). And so on, until the most unbalanced distributions, 1x900 or 900x1 (difference of 899)

EDIT2:
I've done so many rewrites and made so many different attempts that I've got my nose in too much. It's not optimised at all, sorry. I need outside help to help me think again.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
## find_combo.sh

# Both arrays are hard written for convenience. Usually it's generated by another function that find all the dividers from a given number.
dividers_1=(1 2 4 6 8 9 12 16 18 24 32 36 48 64)
dividers_2=(1 2 3 4 7 9 12 16 18 24 27 32 36 48 54)
product=$1

# check if combination is valid
is_valid_combination() {
    local result=$1
    for elem in "${dividers_1[@]}" "${dividers_2[@]}"; do
        if [ "$elem" == "$result" ]; then
            return 0  # valid
        fi
    done
    return 1  #not valid
}

# Find the most balanced combination
balanced_combination=""
min_difference=999999999  #initial value

for num1 in "${dividers_1[@]}"; do
    for num2 in "${dividers_2[@]}"; do
        result=$((num1 * num2))
        difference=$((num1 > num2 ? num1 - num2 : num2 - num1))

        if [ "$result" -eq "$product" ] && [ "$difference" -lt "$min_difference" ] && is_valid_combination "$num1" && is_valid_combination "$num2"; then
            balanced_combination="$num1 x $num2"
            min_difference="$difference"
        fi
    done
done

# check if a balanced combination is found
if [ -n "$balanced_combination" ]; then
    echo "Found it: $balanced_combination"
else
    echo "Sorry, no combination found for $product"
fi
```

`./find_combo.sh 64` should return `Found it: 4 x 16`

Comment: please define what you mean by *`most balanced combination`* and *`distributed as evenly as possible`*; I'm ***guessing*** you mean you want the smallest difference between the multiplicand and multiplier (eg, `4-4 = 0`, `16-1 = 16`, 0 is smaller than 16 so you want `4x4`) ... ??

Comment: *`the most balanced combination becomes 4x12 (or 12x4)`* ... and what is the expected result if there are two 'balanced' combinations? which one is 'correct'?

Comment: please update the question with the code you've tried and the (wrong) output generated by your code; SO is not a code writing service, nor do we complete homework assignments ... you're expected to show your coding attempts and if you have technical/coding issues then post a question and we may be able to help; consider reviewing [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back and update the question

Comment: @markp-fuso That's exactly what I mean by evenly distributed.
In a multiplication where the two terms are evenly distributed, the terms are ideally identical, or at best the difference should be the smallest.
For example, if the product you are looking for is 900, the ideal distribution is `30x30` (a difference of 0) . The next most balanced distribution would be `25x36` or `36x25` (difference of 11). And so on, until the most unbalanced distributions, `1x900` or `900x1` (difference of 899).

Comment: update the question with those details re: 'most balanced / even distribution'; not everyone is going to read through comments trying to piece together the details necessary to understand the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

dividers_1=(1 2 4 6 8 9 12 16 18 24 32 36 48 64)
dividers_2=(1 2 3 4 7 9 12 16 18 24 27 32 36 48 54)

product=$1

# Set up the `divs_2_set` array, which implements the set of numbers in
# `dividers_2`.  The indices are the elements of `dividers_2` and the values
# are the `_` character (an arbitrary non-empty string).
divs_2_set=()
for i in "${dividers_2[@]}"; do
    divs_2_set[i]=_
done

# Below `f1` and `f2` are the current factors of the product and `bf1` and
# `bf2` are the most "balanced" factors found so far.
mindiff='' bf1='' bf2=''
for f1 in "${dividers_1[@]}"; do
    (( product % f1 > 0 )) && continue
    f2=$(( product/f1 ))
    [[ -n ${divs_2_set[f2]-} ]] || continue
    diff=$((f1-f2))
    (( diff < 0 )) && diff=$(( -diff ))
    if [[ -z $mindiff || diff -lt mindiff ]]; then
        mindiff=$diff
        bf1=$f1
        bf2=$f2
    fi
done

if [[ -n $bf1 ]]; then
    printf 'Found it: %d = %d x %d\n' "$product" "$bf1" "$bf2"
else
    printf 'Sorry, no combination found for %d\n' "$product"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I will take some time to read your version.
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

OP's current code:

- the `is_valid_combination()` function appears to be redundant (ie, why test if `$num1 / $num2` are elements in the arrays if these variables are populated from said arrays?)
- remove the `is_valid_combination()` function and the current code works as expected (eg, `64 => 4x16`, `63 => 9x7`, `16 => 4x4`, `5 => Sorry, no combo`)

Nested loops in the shell are not very efficient, especially as the number of elements in the arrays increases.  Using the same algorithm it should be possible to get better performance with a different tool/software (eg, `awk`, `perl`, `python`, etc).

One `awk` approach to implementing the same logic (plus a couple shortcuts to skip processing where `num1`, `num2` or `num1 x num2` are greater than `$product`):

```
$ cat combo
#!/bin/bash

dividers_1=(1 2 4 6 8 9 12 16 18 24 32 36 48 64)
dividers_2=(1 2 3 4 7 9 12 16 18 24 27 32 36 48 54)
product=$1

awk -v prod="${product}" '                                           # assign awk variable "prod" the value of shell variable "product"

BEGIN     { min_diff = 999999999 }

$1 > prod { next }                                                   # both files: if an array element is greater than prod then skip it

FNR==NR   { num1[++cnt] = $1; next }                                 # 1st file: save value in array num1[]

          { num2 = $1                                                # 2nd file: make note of current value as "num2"
            for (i=1; i<=cnt; i++) {                                 # loop through array num1[]
                curr_prod = num1[i] * num2
                curr_diff = (num1[i]>num2 ? num1[i]-num2 : num2-num1[i])

                if ( curr_prod == prod && curr_diff < min_diff) {    # if current prod equals prod and we have a new min diff then ...
                   bal_combo = num1[i] " x " num2                    # make note of the balanced combo and ...
                   min_diff  = curr_diff                             # save the new min diff
                }
                else
                if ( curr_prod > prod )                              # since inputs are sorted, if current product is too big then skip rest of div1[] and ...
                   next                                              # skip to next line of input
            }
          }

END       { if (bal_combo)                                           # after both files have been read: if we have a balanced combo (ie, "bal_combo" is not empty) then ...
               print "Found it:", bal_combo
            else
               print "Sorry, no combination found for",prod
          }
' <(printf "%s\n" "${dividers_1[@]}" | sort -n) <(printf "%s\n" "${dividers_2[@]}" | sort -n)
```

Where:

- `<(printf "%s\n" "${dividers_X[@]}" | sort -n)` - print each array entry to a separate line, sort (numerically) and feed to `awk`; `awk` will process each of these `<(printf | sort)` constructs as a separate 'file'

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ ./combo 16
Found it: 4 x 4

$ ./combo 64
Found it: 16 x 4

$ ./combo 63
Found it: 9 x 7

$ ./combo 5
Sorry, no combination found for 5
```

**NOTES:**

- OP has not provided details on what to do if more than one set of `num1 / num2` pairs *a)* when multiplied together equal `$product` and *b)* have the same (min) diff (eg, `64 = 4 x 16` and `64 => 16 x 4`)
- in this scenario the `awk` script will keep record of (and print) the first `num1 / num2` pair we process

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I never used this kind of approach.
About the first point of your note, it wasn't a deal at the moment. First of all, I was looking for something functional. I'm going to think about your approach first and see how I can draw inspiration from it. Then I'll see how I can develop it further.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need purely shell-only code, a combo of utilities makes it loop-less and straight forward :

```
 printf '%s\n' $dividers_1 | 

 sed -E "s/.+/$( printf '& %s\\n' $dividers_2 )/g" | 

 awk -v ___="$product" 'BEGIN { ___ += _++ == (__ = _++) } ___ == $_ * $__'
```

---

```
1 16
4 4
8 2
16 1
```

Frrom here on, the de-duping and most balanced selection should be trivial

The key savings stemming from the sub-process that dynamically generates a `regex` replacement string equivalent to :

```
sed -E 's/.+/& 1\n& 2\n& 3\n& 4\n ... & 36\n& 48\n& 54\n/g'
```

And you can even extend this approach to handle an array of different products, to be calculated all at once :

```
products_arr=( 16 63 81 144 192 256 384 )

printf '%s\n' $dividers_1 | 
sed -E "s/.+/$( printf '& %s\\n' $dividers_2 )/g" |

awk -v __="$products_arr" 'BEGIN { $+_ = __; while(_++ < NF)___[$_]
    
   NF = (__ = _ ^= !_) < __++ } ($++NF = $_ * $__) in ___'
```

---

```
1 16 16
4 4 16
4 36 144
4 48 192
6 24 144
6 32 192
8 2 16
8 18 144
8 24 192
8 32 256
8 48 384
9 7 63
9 9 81
9 16 144
12 12 144
12 16 192
12 32 384
16 1 16
16 9 144
16 12 192
16 16 256
16 24 384
24 16 384
32 12 384
36 4 144
48 3 144
48 4 192
64 3 192
64 4 256
```